# If a is non zero non unit in a PID then a has at least one irreducible divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

Sources for the proof of this claim: If $a$ is non zero non unit in a PID then $a$ has at least one irreducible divisor.

Definition of irreducible element: a non zero non unit element $p$ is irreducible if whenever $p=ab$, then $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

Note: I need this step to prove that every PID is UFD.

One user's answer:

Let R be said PID and suppose a∈R is a nonzero non-unit. Then, the principal ideal aR is nonzero and proper (i.e. aR≠{0} and aR≠R). Therefore, aR is contained in a maximal ideal M, which is principal. Therefore M=pR and a∈aR⊂pR. That means that a=pr for some r∈R∖{0}, so we just need to prove p is irreducible. Well, otherwise, p=xy for some non-units x,y∈R, which would imply pR⊊xR⊊R contradicting the maximality of pR.

What I don't understand in the answer :

Why if p is not irreducible then it implies p=xy, where x and y are non-units? This is the only step that I still can't grasp?

Comment: A PID is a UFD and so every nonzero nonunit in a PID is a product of irreducibles.

Comment: I need this step to prove the theorem you just mentioned. Can you please see the below answer and my comment?

Comment: Better clarify the context in the question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be said PID and suppose $a\in R$ is a nonzero non-unit. Then, the principal ideal $aR$ is nonzero and proper (i.e. $aR\neq\{0\}$ and $aR\neq R$). Therefore, $aR$ is contained in a maximal ideal $M$, which is principal. Therefore $M=pR$ and $a\in aR\subset pR$. That means that $a=pr$ for some $r\in R\backslash\{0\}$, so we just need to prove $p$ is irreducible. Well, otherwise, $p=xy$ for some non-units $x,y\in R$, which would imply $pR\subsetneq xR\subsetneq R$ contradicting the maximality of $pR$.

Comment: Is there a way to use the fact that any chain of principle ideals must terminate in PID to prove the claim?

Comment: @I0_0I: it implies that $(a)$ is contained in a maximal ideal, by looking at the collection of all proper ideals that contain $(a)$.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.

Comment: @I0_0I Based on your comment (and prior question), likely you seek [this form of the proof via ACCP](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/830596/242)

Comment: Why if $p$ is not irreducible then it implies $p=xy$, where $x$ and $y$ are non-units? This is the only step that I still can't grasp.

Comment: 14 is not irreducible but 14=14*1

Comment: @I0_0I: It's the *definition* of irreducible: an element $a$ is irreducible if and only if whenever $a=xy$, either $x$ is a unit or $y$ is a unit. It doesn't mean *every* expression of $p$ as a product has both factors non-units, it just says there *exists* an expression $p$ as a product with both factors nonunits.

Comment: I see your point. But I can't see how the definition of irreducible element implies that! If p is irreducible then the definition tells us something about p. But if p is not irreducible then the definition doesn't tell us anything about the element p. Isn't it the 'convers is true falasy' to imply any property on the element p which is not irreducible?

Comment: I'm thinking of irreducible element in context of a ring. Without using any implicit assumptions and properties. How does it follow that there exist x and y non units such that $p=xy$? I'm not stupid I swear!

Comment: I'm stuck on this since the past 4 days

Comment: Just explain to me like you would explain it to Forrest Gump.

Comment: The definition is $$\mbox{"($p$ is irreducible) $\iff$ (for every factorization $p=xy$, either $x$ is a unit or $y$ is a unit)}$$. Now, negate the statements on both sides of $\iff$ to get the logically equivalent statement $$\mbox{($p$ is not irreducible) $\iff$ (there exists a factorization $p=xy$ where both $x$ and $y$ are not units)}$$

Comment: Thank you sir finally.

Comment: We have to prove that there exists some factorization of p though right? Or maybe If p is not factorlizable it implies it's irreducible?

Comment: $p=p\cdot 1$ is a trivial factorization.

Comment: OK ok kk I get it now thank you so much